# document.getElementById returns a null value, but only when executed within a multiline script. Returns correct element when executed by itself

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

---

I am creating a script to automate a data entry process on a server monitoring website. The site does not have an API for this specific data entry type, so I am using JavaScript to automate the mouse clicking and data entry process.

The script returns the correct document.getElementById("") value for getElement statement. However, it only returns the correct value whenever I manually execute line of individually. If I run the entire script, then the code breaks on one single line.

```
`var namesAndAddresses = { 'DomainName': 'IP' };

//Function to press sidebar "add device button"
function MenuFunction() {

    MenuId = document.getElementById("menurow_Add/Import Devices").firstChild.nextElementSibling;

    MenuId.click()
}
//Function to press "add device manually button"
function AddDeviceFunction() {

    AddDeviceButton = document.getElementById("addDeviceButtonId_label");

    AddDeviceButton.click();

}
//Function to add device information and then press the save button
function AddDeviceInformationFunction(domain, address) {

    FQDN = document.getElementById("deviceNameId").value =
        domain; //FQDN;

    deviceClass = document.getElementById("deviceClassId").value =
        "Switch/Router";

    OS = document.getElementById("deviceOsId").value =
        "Other Operating System";

    ipAddress = document.getElementById("customUriId").value =
        address; //DictionaryID;

    licenseMode = document.getElementById("licenseModeId").value =
        "Professional Mode";

    saveButton = document.getElementById("cancelButtonId"); //change to save button

    saveButton.click();
}

//manually wait function
function pause(milliseconds) {
    var dt = new Date();
    while ((new Date()) - dt <= milliseconds) { /* Do nothing */ }
}

//For loop to add each domain and ip that is listed in the dictionary
for (var [domainName, IP] of Object.entries(namesAndAddresses)) {

    window.self = document;
    //Function to press sidebar "add device button"
    MenuFunction();

    //Insert wait for sub-page to load here
    pause(3000);

    //Function to press "add device manually button" **THIS IS THE FUNCTION THAT RETURNS NULL**
    AddDeviceFunction();

    //Insert wait for objects to load here
    pause(5000);

    //Function to add device information and then press the save button
    AddDeviceInformationFunction(domainName, IP);

    //Insert wait for objects to load here

    pause(5000);

};`
```

HTML code is below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Bngn.png)

I have tried adding in a manual "wait" because window.onload does not work due to all the HTML being loaded already. I also tried adding a try/catch statement within a loop, so that it could make the attempt 10 times over a period of 10 seconds. That didn't work either.

Comment: `"menurow_Add/Import Devices"` is really an id?

Comment: All that pause code does is lock up the browser.

Comment: Surprisingly, yes. Selecting on that ID and clicking it actually works every time. Whether executed within the script or by a single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code's `pause` function is blocking.

What this means is that since it "waits" using a while loop, it is not actually waiting but doing a lot of useless work, using up 100% of the CPU, and preventing anything else from actually loading.

Because of this, I can only presume the elements that are supposed to appear when loading do not get a chance to, meaning `getElementById` returns null (they do not exist yet)

Consider using something like `setTimeout`, which will properly wait, without preventing other work from being done.

Replace your for loop near the end with

```js
var entries = Object.entries(namesAndAddresses)
window.self = document;
function processEntry(){
    if(!entries.length){
        // Done
        return
    }
    
    // Get (and remove) the first element in the array
    var [domainName, IP] = entries.shift()

    //Function to press sidebar "add device button"
    MenuFunction();

    //Wait for sub-page to load using setTimeout, which will run this code after 3000ms
    setTimeout(function(){
        //Function to press "add device manually button" **THIS IS THE FUNCTION THAT RETURNS NULL**
        AddDeviceFunction();

        //Wait for objects to load here
        setTimeout(function(){
            //Function to add device information and then press the save button
            AddDeviceInformationFunction(domainName, IP);

            //Insert wait for objects to load here
            setTimeout(function(){
                // Done, go to next entry
                processEntry();
            }, 5000);
        }, 5000);
    }, 3000);
};
processEntry()
```

I would also recommend looking into promises and [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), which can make this code look much neater:

```js
function pause(milliseconds) {
    return new Promise(function(finish){
        setTimeout(finish, milliseconds)
    })
}
async function processAllEntries(){
    //For loop to add each domain and ip that is listed in the dictionary
    for (var [domainName, IP] of Object.entries(namesAndAddresses)) {
    
        window.self = document;
        //Function to press sidebar "add device button"
        MenuFunction();
    
        //Insert wait for sub-page to load here
        await pause(3000);
    
        //Function to press "add device manually button" **THIS IS THE FUNCTION THAT RETURNS NULL**
        AddDeviceFunction();
    
        //Insert wait for objects to load here
        await pause(5000);
    
        //Function to add device information and then press the save button
        AddDeviceInformationFunction(domainName, IP);
    
        //Insert wait for objects to load here
        await pause(5000);
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pause causes the UI not to be able to render. You can make a function that uses await to look for an element. As soon as it is available it will update.

```js
function addElem() {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = 'foo';
  div.textContent = 'hello';
  document.body.append(div);
}


const waitForElem = (selector) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const check = () => {
    const elem = document.querySelector(selector);
    if (elem) {
      resolve(elem);
    } else {
      window.setTimeout(check, 1);
    }
  };
  check();
});

window.setTimeout(addElem, 5000);

(async function() {

  const el1 = await waitForElem('#bar');
  el1.textContent = 'found 1';

  const el2 = await waitForElem('.foo');
  el2.textContent = 'found 2';

})();
```

```html
<div id="bar">Test</div>
```